# How do I view older iterations of binary (image or non-code) files from a git repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am currently using BitBucket's git system to manage my repositories. I see my old code, however when I try to see older iterations of image (PNG) files, all I see are the following:

[image: History View]

AND when I try to access the image from the older commit:

[image: Old Repo Access]

Any input on how to get such files would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see your file, using the address accessing the **raw** content:

```
https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>/raw/<revision>/yourpicture.png
```

See for instance https://bitbucket.org/wuub/kmagik/raw/c1fd2c3c64b7/screen1-hi.png

[image: screenshot from bitbucket]

As mention in this [BitBucket documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Source), you can use curl to directly get your document.

Answer (score 3):

You can check it out locally as well with

```
git checkout HEAD^^^^^^ -- path/to/pic.png
```

or if you want to put it somewhere else

```
git show HEAD^^^^^^:path/to/pic.png > /some/other/path/pic.png
```

and then view it on your machine with a browser